# How to handle routes in angularjs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am learning angularjs with rails but i got stuck, when i request

```
http://localhost:3000/#/users
```

it renders the default rails welocome page

below is my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});


app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/users',{
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl'
        }
    );
 }]);
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>Books</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container" ng-view>
     <%= yield %>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new route:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'angular#index'
```

and a controller with an action:

```
# app/controllers/angular_controller.rb
class AngularController < ApplicationController
  def index; end
end
```

and a template with `ng-view`:

```
# views/angular/index.html.erb
<div class="container" ng-view>
</div>
```

I would not recommend to put `ng-view` in `layouts/application`, better place it in page template file.

Now default Rails page should be gone and you can test your Angular application.